# i want to read the data from website the website contains downloadable files and then i want to send it to the oracle using python script how?

Tags: python

I want to read the data from website the website contains down-loadable files and then i want to send it to the oracle using python script how??

the website is WWW.EODDATA.COM

Comment: The oracle only accepts messages in COBOL, for that is the one true language.

Comment: If you put a bit more thought into the question, and describe what problems you are facing and what you have tried, it would be a lot easier to help you. Try reading this for tips on how to ask a good question: http://www.gerv.net/hacking/how-to-ask-good-questions/

Answer (score 0):

Look into [urllib](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html) and some sort of xml parser like [xml.dom.minidom](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html). I've never messed with oracle so I don't know a good library but it looks like oracle provides a python library: http://wiki.oracle.com/page/Python